# MYSQL query to find strings that are like a concatenated string

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a sales database that contains all of our sales and credits by invoice number.

I need to find all invoices that do not have a credit issued against them.

Luckily, our credit memos are the invoice number with `CM` in front of the original invoice number.

For example, the credit for invoice number `123456` would be `CM123456`

I imagine I would use some form of `concat()`, but I am not sure of the format of the query or if it is even possible.

Comment: Can you concatenate the string before you execute the query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, replace tablename

```
SELECT concat('CM",invoice_number) from tablename
```

To find the Invoices with CM as prefix you can use

```
Select * from tablename where column_name like 'CM%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer lies in the `LIKE` keyword, which uses wildcards to filter the results.
The `%` character means any number of any characters.
I think something like `WHERE credit_invoice_number NOT LIKE "CM%"` would suits your needs.
You can find more info in the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE invoice NOT LIKE 'CM%';
```